# Microsoft Word insert new equation shows a sort of blue bracklet box

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equations

Everytime I insert a new equation, it appears between two weirdd bluish box schaped bracklets with gray font color. It started a few days ago and I never had this before.

I thought a computer reboot or program restart might fix the problem, but it reappeared again and now it does not go away. How do I get it back to normal?

See photo here.
[Microsoft Word inser new equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jax3Z.png)

After selecting the whole box and type something, the equation turns back to normal, but I have to do this for every new equation.

Answer (score 0):

That's a Design Mode bracket on a Content Control. Go to the Developer tab and click the Design Mode toggle button. It's in the Controls Group. I think a recent pushed update on Office has accidentally set the toggle switch to ON.

Once you set it to OFF it should stay that way.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I didn't have the Developer tab enabled, had to do that first through options and customize ribbon.